# Evaluating the limit of a function involving exponential and hypergeometric functions as it approaches infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to evaluate the limit of
$$
e^{-BY} \left[ 
B \,e^{2Y} {}_2F_1 \left( 1,1-\frac{B}{2}; 2-\frac{B}{2}; -e^{-2Y} \right)
-(B-2)\, {}_2F_1 \left( 1,-\frac{B}{2}; 1-\frac{B}{2}; -e^{-2Y} \right)
\right] \, ,
$$
as $Y \to \infty$.

For $B=1$, it appears that the limit is $\pi$. I'm curious if a closed analytical form can be derived for arbitrary values of $B$. Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Mathematica indicates $$\underset{Y\to \infty }{\text{lim}}e^{-B Y} \left(B\, e^{2 Y} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{B}{2};2-\frac{B}{2};-e^{-2 Y}\right)-(B-2) \, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{B}{2};1-\frac{B}{2};-e^{-2 Y}\right)\right)=\infty\,\quad 0<B<2.$$

Comment: @StevenClark No. It is not. Why should then get $\pi$ for $B=1$ then.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BE%5E%28-1+Y%29+%281+E%5E%282+Y%29+Hypergeometric2F1%5B1%2C+1-1%2F2%2C+2-1%2F2%2C+-E%5E%28-2+Y%29%5D-%281-2%29+Hypergeometric2F1%5B1%2C+-%281%2F2%29%2C+1-1%2F2%2C+-E%5E%28-2+Y%29%5D%29%2C+Y-%3EInfinity%5D) gives the same result for $B=1$ and also the series expansion at $Y=\infty$. Maybe there's a typo somewhere?

Comment: @StevenClark Use $Y=10^3$ for instance and evaluate the expression numerically. You will see that it approaches $\pi$

Comment: For $B=1$ the function

$$f_B(Y)=e^{-B Y} \left(B\, e^{2 Y} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{B}{2};2-\frac{B}{2};-e^{-2 Y}\right)-(B-2) \, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{B}{2};1-\frac{B}{2};-e^{-2 Y}\right)\right)\tag{1}$$

simplifies to

$$f_1(Y)=e^Y \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-e^{-2 Y}\right)+e^{-Y} \, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2};-e^{-2 Y}\right)\tag{2}.$$

Noting that $\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};0\right)=\, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2};0\right)=1$, its not too hard to see that $\lim\limits_{Y\to\infty}f_1(Y)=\infty$.